# Drawing image over static control

Tags: c++, c, winapi, picturebox

I'm trying to paint a Picture Box over Static Control, yet the image is not appearing.

The image do exist at the location.

Here is my code :

```
    HWND hwn = CreateWindow(TEXT("static"), NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 5, 10, 470, 100, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    HBITMAP hBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "D:\\Pic.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 100, 100, LR_LOADFROMFILE);  
SendMessage(hwn, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBmp);
```

First I'm creating a static control (just as the guides in google said), and then I'm painting the image over it... Why isnt it working ? It only draws the static control, but the image isnt being loaded at all...

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need SS_BITMAP style when creating the static control.